# Can you use olive oil past its expiration date?

Tags: oil, olive-oil

I just noticed my olive oil expired on 2016/6, however, I couldn't tell that by taste and it still seems fine to use.

Can I continue on using it? It seems such a waste to throw it away since it still works well for frying/cooking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it tastes and smells fine, I would still use it. It won't do you any harm. It may just have a diminished/diminishing flavor.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of oil ever expiring. In fact it's commonly used to preserve food (for example dried tomatoes) because it traps out air and avoids bacterial growth. I suppose is a "best consumed before" more than a proper expiry date.

Comment: Actually, it can go rancid, even before expiration date - but that also makes it taste worse or even unpalatable.